# Dot sourcing a file one level below?

Tags: powershell, scripting

So I'm trying to dot course a logging functions file, but it will reside one level up from the $PSScriptRoot value.

I've tried `. "..\$PSScriptRoot\Functions\Logging_Functions.ps1"` which I thought was working but turns out it was not.

What's an appropriate syntax for relative paths for a situation like this?

Comment: Why do you have `$PSScriptRoot` in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$PSScriptRoot` is already a rooted path, you can't use it in the middle of a relative one (eg. `..\C:\a\path\somewhere`).

Instead, you'll want to use it at the *start* of the path string:

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\..\Functions\Logging_Functions.ps1"
```

Path globber will now resolve `..` relative to `$PSScriptRoot`

Comment: Nice.. I had suspicions.  Thanks MJ